# I'm facing difficulty in creating cookie using node js with AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, lambda

I i'm trying to create a cookie on node js side with the help of aws lambda. I have tried this below link to create cookie but I'm able to set cookie with context.done or context.successed. With this aproch cookie get printed on browser and your code get exits. What I'm trying to do its set a cookie and then execute other functions. 
With navtive node js, you have to use http.createClient or createServer to get http.serverResponse but with aws lambda you can't do it.

AWS link to create cookie with AWS api gatewal and lambda. I'm able to achieve this.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simply-serverless-using-aws-lambda-to-expose-custom-cookies-with-api-gateway/

**Edit**
Adding code what I'm trying to do,

```
 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    console.log("{'Cookie':event['Cookie']}");
  var date = new Date();

  // Get Unix milliseconds at current time plus 365 days
  date.setTime(+ date + (365 * 86400000)); //24 \* 60 \* 60 \* 100
  var cookieVal = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7); // Generate a random cookie string

  var cookieString = "mycookie="+cookieVal+"; expires="+date.toGMTString()+";";
  var errorXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><VAST version="3.0"><error>Ad Not Available</error></VAST>';
   console.log(event.params.header["Cookie"]);

        if(event.params.header["Cookie"]){
            console.log(errorXml);
            callback(null, "test");
        }else{
            console.log("setting cookie");

            callback(null, {errorXml,"Cookie":cookieString});
        }

};
```

With I'm able to set the cookie but as my o/p is xml, and I'm passing Cookie in callback function (I think this is the only way to set cookie in node js using lambda. I may be wrong). application/xml is creating issue for valid xml. Once cookie is set code isn't going in else loop. In my application is I can check if Cookie is set in header or not and pass it to some variable. Now I'm having issue in setting cookie, with callback.

Answer (score 0):

*Writing this answer based on assumptions. In case it doesn't help, Please provide some code to get into details. Also, the exact code without any further additions in the [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simply-serverless-using-aws-lambda-to-expose-custom-cookies-with-api-gateway/) you provided works for me.*

> With this approach cookie get printed on browser and your code get exits.

I suppose that your function exits before successful execution.

Reasons may be:

*Timeout*: This reason can be verified through the log [*Task timed out after x seconds*]

*Lambda being Asynchronous* : If the cookie gets printed after `callback` and function exits, it may be possible that your other functions have greater execution time and callback is called before others' execution completes.
This can be verified by adding a `console.log("test data");` inside every other function to track their execution.

> What I'm trying to do its set a cookie and then execute other functions.

well, if your cookie doesn't need any data from 'other functions', this can be achieved, but if you call `context` or any `callbacks` outside 'other functions', chances are, asynchronous Node will execute `context.done()` first.

My suggestions:

**case 1**:

If you have nested functions and cookie needs data from one of those--
You should go for *promises*, this will ensure, data is returned and post that cookie can be set.
More about Promise can be found: [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise)

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
get('http://www.google.com', function (err, res) {
if (err) reject(err);
else resolve(res);
  });
});
```

**case 2:**

If no dependency on other functions--

Try using callback
something like :

```
 exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
 otherFunctions(){}
 callback(null, {"Cookie": cookieString});
}
```

Comment: with your last method I'm already able to set the cookie but this call back exits the function i.e. export handler. I'm new to node js, can I set this cookie to any variable in a function and return the value after function get executed.

Comment: Appears, You have nested functions with variable execution times and node returns callback before execution completes. You can set a Boolean value as False and make it True once you get all the nested functions are done executing. Then, use IF Condition to check whether Boolean is true, if so, return callback. Or, learn to use promises in these cases. Will help for sure.

Comment: using Boolean worked for you? or you applied something else. please let us know.

Comment: I have updated question with code. I'm still stuck at the same issue.

Comment: I have sorted the issue. You have to set your cookie at final callback but if you wish not to print it on browser, you have to set correct response at integration response body template. Only pass body and other json variable that you wish to print. In my case I wanted to print only body so I used $inputRoot.body and modifying above code callback(null, {"body":errorXml,"Cookie":cookieString}); I was able to set the cookie.